# Google App Engine : Wrong Serving Url

Tags: image, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, serving

I have created a Google App Engine project where it's possible to upload photos. Uploading part is working fine and all the photos are uploaded in proper size. But when I try getting **images.get_serving_url** , it returns me serving_url appended with *lh3.googleusercontent.com* but according to GoogleAppEngine documentation it must return serving_url something like *lh3.gghpt.com* . Also, the problem which comes is that the photos on that serving_url is 4-6 times smaller than the uploaded ones and when I view in the GoogleAppEngine console, all those photos have same size as the uploaded ones. I don't know why GoogleAppEngine is not returning the actual sized images.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying size=0 in the images.get_serving_url method call.
eg. `images.get_serving_url(blob_key, size=0)`